# What is the ship in this scene?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, star-wars-rebels, object-identification

At the end of the *Star Wars Rebels* episode "[The Lost Commanders](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Commanders)", an Inquisitor on a Lambda-class shuttle enters the docking bay of Agent Callus' Star Destroyer.

To the right of the shuttle are parked several TIE Fighters, while to its left are parked several craft which I have just seen for the first time *(see freehand red circle)*. They looked to me like an Imperial version of the LAAT Republic Gunships.

Does anyone know their exact name, model, specs etc?

[image]

Comment: I think that's a Sentinel class shuttle, not Lambda

Comment: @DVK Any supporting evidence? I searched up the two classes, they don't appear to be visually distinguishable.

Comment: Good point. There seems to be some discrepancy in what the size is between different sources, and some list the sizes as identical. Most of the difference is internal.

Comment: @DVK From Wookiepedia, it can be seen that the Sentinel-class appears to be more suited for frontline use: double the size for double the troop carrying capacity, ability to carry light armor like AT-STs, heavier armaments including projectile ammo, hull armor and shields. The Lambda is for lighter use by the military and government - it allows for conversion of the internal design to hold staterooms. Considering who is being transported in this picture, I would think a Lambda is more likely.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108906/how-do-i-know-if-a-shuttle-is-sentinel-or-lambda-class-visually

Comment: @thegreatjedi From the side, the Sentinel and the Lambda-class couldn't be more different. See DVK's question (linked to in his comment).

Answer (score 18):

They are [Police Gunships](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Police_gunship):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> The police gunship, also known first as the Republic police gunship or Republic police helicopter and later as the Imperial patrol transport, was a gunship introduced during the Clone Wars to perform law enforcement functions on the Republic capital of Coruscant. Designed to be sleeker and smaller as well as less heavily armed than the Republic attack gunship, the police gunship was better suited for policing the dense city-wide planet while reducing the risks of collateral damage. The police gunship was armed with ball-mounted turrets and fixed cannons. A troop bay allowed for the rapid deployment of police officers. Though utilized primarily by the Coruscant Security Force, the police gunship also was available to the Coruscant Guard shock troopers who could procure them if need be. After the formation of the Galactic Empire, the police gunship saw a broader use as a patrol craft for the Imperial military on various worlds.
>   -  [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Police_gunship)

And:

> POLICE GUNSHIP
>   During the Clone Wars, security on Coruscant was bolstered with the addition of Republic police gunships. Smaller, sleeker, and less heavily-armed than the military-grade Republic attack gunship, the police gunship was better suited to navigate the skyline and was less likely to cause costly collateral damage with its pair of ball-mounted laser turrets that flanked the cockpit, or the a fixed laser cannon that extended from the rear. Four arm-mounted solar gather panels helped power the repulsorlift vehicle. The control cabin had two stacked seats, with the pilot elevated and slightly behind the gunner. The troop bay had side doors that folded upward for entry, and rear ramp for rapid deployment of police forces. After the Clone Wars, the Empire made equally good use of police gunships, using them to combat rebel threats from world to world.
>   - [Star Wars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank/police-gunship)

Answer (score 10):

This is a Police Gunship.

Canon reference: SW Databank: http://www.starwars.com/databank/police-gunship

Databank specs are somewhat scant:

Dimensions

```
Length: 11.48m
Height: 5.43m
Width: 5.76m
```

And the Databank writeup is:

> During the Clone Wars, security on Coruscant was bolstered with the addition of Republic police gunships. Smaller, sleeker, and less heavily-armed than the military-grade Republic attack gunship, the police gunship was better suited to navigate the skyline and was less likely to cause costly collateral damage with its **pair of ball-mounted laser turrets that flanked the cockpit, or the a fixed laser cannon that extended from the rear. Four arm-mounted solar gather panels helped power the repulsorlift vehicle. The control cabin had two stacked seats, with the pilot elevated and slightly behind the gunner. The troop bay had side doors that folded upward for entry, and rear ramp for rapid deployment of police forces**. After the Clone Wars, the Empire made equally good use of police gunships, using them to combat rebel threats from world to world.

Wikia article: 
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Police_gunship

[image]

It originated in Clone Wars, but according to Wikia appears in at least 2 Rebels episodes:

Star Wars Rebels – "Call to Action"

Star Wars Rebels – "Relics of the Old Republic"