# How do I know if a shuttle is Sentinel or Lambda class visually?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

[Sentinel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinel-class_landing_craft) and [Lambda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lambda-class_T-4a_shuttle) shuttles seem to be very closely related and similar in appearance:

> With its folding wing configuration and matching cockpit module, the Sentinel-class landing craft was based on the Lambda-class shuttle, both shuttles having seen design origins in the Theta-class shuttle (Wikia)

Is there a reliable way to tell whether a shuttle is Lambda or Sentinel class visually? (e.g. in a film/cartoon scene)? Such as different shapes, detailing, colors, etc...?

I will accept size at last resort since in some visual scenes you can see the shuttle next to another known-size craft or object; but I strongly prefer other methods that would work even if the shuttle is the only object in visible frame of reference.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to [Jason Baker's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108908/770), the side-view schematics of both shuttles make it very evident that they are only superficially similar. In fact, they are *extremely* different from the side!

(All images taken from Wookieepedia, but the original source is [The Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034539299X))

**Lambda-class**:
[image]

**Sentinel-class**:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

For reference:

**[*Sentinel*-class Shuttle](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-sentinel-class-shuttle)**

[image]

**[*Lambda*-class Shuttle](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-shuttle)**

[image]

<sup>Both images from the StarWars.com databank</sup>

It's pretty easy to pick up on some differences looking at them side-by-side:

- The *Lambda* has landing lights on the wingtips, while the *Sentinel* has them nearer the main body of the ship
- The *Sentinel*'s main viewport is more triangular, following the point of the nose
- The joints on the lower two wings are much bulkier in the *Sentinel*, possibly for increased cargo space

  - In these two comparison images, we can see that the entire cargo section on the *Sentinel* is significantly larger:

    *Sentinel*:

    [image]

    <sup>From *Star Wars Rebels*</sup>

    *Lambda*:

    [image]

    <sup>From *Return of the Jedi*</sup>
- The cockpit of the *Sentinel* sits higher up from that of the *Lambda*, probably because of the larger cargo area

Comment: +1 The [side view schematics of the *Sentinel*](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/3/3a/Sentinel_schem.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081008144239) make it even more evident that it looks significantly different from a *Lambda*-class.

Answer (score -3):

The Sentinel shuttle's extension pod has a flat bottom to facilitate airlift of AT-ST walker pods by attaching them to the bottom of the shuttle and airdropping them on the battlefield to release the walker for action.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your answer? An image or quote, perhaps?